# How to trigger php script using google appscript when new email receive

Tags: php, mobile, gmail, sms

as title it posible ? or other solution is recommended !

what i want is send sms to my phone with important email from my BOSS

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Solution could be:
1. Check Emails via PHP-Cronscript over IMAP 
2. If an Email is received from your Boss, you can send a SMS-Notification.